# Percent with do or does?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

1) How many students, in our University, **does** 10 percent comprise?

2) How many students, in our University, **do** 10 percent comprise?

Is this one correct or not? I am not sure.

3) How many students, in our University, comprise 10 percent?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, "How many students, in our University, do 10 percent comprise?" is correct. The subject is "students", which is plural, so "do" is the proper verb.

However, it would sound better to ask "In our university, how many students comprise 10 percent?"

Comment: The subject here is not "students", but "10%".  compare "how many flies does a spider eat in a week?"

Answer (score 1):

Percent is both a singular and plural noun. If the percent is used with a singular or uncountable noun, it'll take a singular auxilliary  verb and if it's used with a plural noun, it'll take a plural verb.

As students is a plural noun, the percentage will take the plural verb. So the second sentence "How many students, in our university, do 10% comprise" is correct.

As for your last sentence "How many students, in our university, comprise 10 percent", I don't see anything wrong with it. Frankly speaking, it sounds simple and more natural to me.

However, my answer may be intelligible to some people and a bit confusing to others.
Actually, in the first sentence, the subject of the verb comprise is 10%, whereas, in my last sentence, the subject of this verb is students. For further clarification, please look up comprise in Macmillan Dictionary).